Pipeline Trigger Issue with Conditional Stages in GitLab CI
I have a GitLab CI pipeline with two stages: test and upload_to_s3. I want the pipeline to run only when a tag is created. To achieve this, I've set up the following rules for each stage:
stages:
  - test
  - upload_to_s3

include:
  - template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

sast:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG

upload_to_s3:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  script:
    # Install zip & git
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip git python3-pip
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG


However, the pipeline is being triggered by the sast stage even when there is no tag, which is not the expected behavior. The upload_to_s3 stage is not triggered, which is as expected when there is no tag.
Could you help me understand why the sast stage is running even without a tag, and how I can ensure that both stages run only when a tag is present?
Thank you!
I want the pipeline to run only when a tag is created.
